# Suggest the change of the default site icon

Tags: support, favicon

How is it possible to suggest a change to a default site icon? I noticed a lot of sites with a default one.

Comment: Do you have examples of sites? The couple I checked all have working fav-icons.

Comment: Do you mean the beta sites which have just a blue balloon with letters or an icon in them?

Comment: yes . exactly that

Comment: economics for example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by "default" you mean the blue text bubble with letters in, that's Beta sites and they get changed when the sites "graduate" out of Beta.

[What does "beta" mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-beta)

> “Beta” means that the site is still being defined and constructed
>
> ...
>
> All beta sites have the same temporary placeholder design. Once the site is no longer beta, it will have a unique design built with input from the community.
>
> ...
>
> There is no set amount of time for a site to remain in beta; it will be in beta for as long as necessary to reach critical mass, with periodic evaluations that help communities know where they stand and what they need to work on.

[image]

[image]